# htaccess rule apply query string rule and change the url

Tags: .htaccess

```
 /index.php?search_category=32
to
/32
```

How to do this by `.htacces`s in a way that when `"/index.php?search_category=32"` appear it auto change to `"/32"` with the same query string rules?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in **the directory your index.php file is in**, you need to add these rules. For example, if the directory is `/xyz/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /xyz/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_category=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ %1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?search_category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is setup so you can swap the htaccess file in any directory as long as you change the `RewriteBase` to the directory the htaccess file is in (including the document root, `/`).

Comment: Thanks for replying 
xampp 1.7.4 installed on my computer and mod_rewrite is on. its redireting me to localhost/xampp/. And its not redirecting this "/index.php?search_category=32" to "/32".

Comment: @HamdIslam I put those rules in a blank htaccess file in a new install of apache, and go to `http://localhost/index.php?search_category=123456` and I get redirected to `http://localhost/123456`. It looks like you are missing a `/` in front of the `%2`

Comment: its not working out bro. in the main document root of folder "xyz" i have my htaccess file "http://localhost/xyz/index.php?search_category=123456" but not getting the response to "http://localhost/xyz/123456" :-( i think we are close

Comment: @HamdIslam `http://localhost/123456` is completely different from `http://localhost/another_directory/123456`. It's not even the same question. Of course this answer isn't going to work.

Comment: kindly make any rule for this another_directory scenario actually my question was this

Comment: @HamdIslam OK, I've changed the answer to reflect that the index.php is in a subdirectory off of the document root.